# Asynchronous service calls on server startup

Tags: java, asynchronous, server-side

I'm trying to create a simple RESTful application that helps people create and retrieve certain objects. The objective of the service is to serve up these objects as quickly as possible, which is why I'm considering cheating a little by "pre-creating" the objects during the server startup time in an asynchronous fashion. I can get away with this model because I know that there are only 500 different flavors of objects that people can ask for so i'd rather have them readily sitting in my persistent store (redis) warmed up such that by the time a user is asking for it, it's ready to serve.

My question is around how to enable this "background/async" processing right around the server startup (for a server like jBoss/tomcat in a RESTful service written in java). Putting it into a static block in the class serving results doesn't work, so I was wondering if there's a config in the catalina files that can link to loading a class which in turn could do the needful.

Comment: Why pre-create them?  It seems that is because you are working around a design flaw.  What type of response are you expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to pre-create them because it takes roughly 30 seconds to create each object. I'm not interested in simply offering a RESTful shim, i'd like to offer some speed so if there's an opportunity to seize some "whitespace" in the idle background where my service can work and generate these objects, then I'd like to shoot for it.

Regardless of whether it's optimal design, is there a simple way to trigger some code on server startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `load-on-startup` in your web.xml file, and then if you use the `Init` method in your `HttpServlet` class you may get the behavior you want.

Load-on-startup is a directive to tell the container to start that class immediately upon startup.

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>ServletOne</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.yourcomp.MainServlet</servlet-class>
    <description>This servlet is an example servlet</description>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Btw, given that I have a relatively expensive process I'd like to run (aka I don't want my server startup time to be 10mins) would it be reasonable to wrap up the heavy processing in an asynchronous fashion so that my server can still "serve" requests once it's initialized in a timely fashion?

Comment: Yes, have the Init method create a thread that starts to do the heavy processing.